# how to get value of variable from one function code into another function php wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, function, variables, global-variables

I have the following (very reduced code) and I want to call the value of the variable $sendmilisecs from the first function in the second function (line 7 from bottom), but every attempt failed. I have tried with global $sendmilisecs, but even that didn't work. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
<?php
function gastats_display_settings() 
{
$sendsecs = 10;
$sendmilisecs = $sendsecs * 1000;
$sopmin = 3;
$gastatssopsecs = $rbrsopmin * 60;
}

function ga_stats() {
echo "
<script>
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
(function (tos) {
window.setInterval(function () {
tos = (function (t) {
  return t[0] == 50 ? (parseInt(t[1]) + 1) + ':00' : (t[1] || '0') + ':' +     (parseInt(t[0]) + 10);
})(tos.split(':').reverse());
window.pageTracker ? pageTracker._trackEvent('Time', 'Log', tos) :  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Time', 'Log', tos]);
}, " . $sendmilisecs . ");
})('00');
</script>
";
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'ga_stats', 100);
?>
```

Comment: Why oh why are you doing it like that? Check [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) and [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script). Writing JavaScript as strings is not good practice.

Comment: I know and I am going to change that later, but for now the question is: how to call the variable.